# How to fit multiple TextField elements into the Grid container using Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/) in order to design my front-end. I have a question regarding Grid layout. I want to put 7 TextField elements, but they look overlapped. If I change `xs={1}` to `xs={2}` for all 7 TextField elements, then become much bigger and they do not fit into a single line.

How can I fit 7 TextField elements into the container adjusting the size automatically?

```
<Grid container spacing={24}>
   <Grid item xs={1}>
      <TextField
          required
          id="holdingTime"
          className={this.props.styles.textField}
          onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("holdingTime", event)}
          value={this.props.state.holdingTime}
          margin="normal"
          label="Holding time"
          type="number"
          InputProps={{
             startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(seconds)</InputAdornment>,
          }}
          onInput = {(e) =>{
             e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
          }}
     />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material-UI's Grid supports [auto-layout](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout). Using a bare breakpoint property (e.g. `<Grid item xs >` which is equivalent to `<Grid item xs={true}>`) indicates to use the auto-layout feature.

The code below shows two Grids. One using auto-layout for all sizes and one using auto-layout when the screen size is medium or wider, 4 text fields per line for small screens (via `sm={3}`), and 3 text fields per line for extra-small screens (via `xs={4}`). Play around with the CodeSandbox at different sizes to see this in action.

See https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#breakpoints for the sizes of the different breakpoints.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>This Grid is always auto-layout.</div>
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map(() => (
          <Grid item xs>
            <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div>
        This Grid changes the number of text fields per line as the screen size
        changes.
      </div>
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map(() => (
          <Grid item xs={4} sm={3} md>
            <TextField required label="4/3/true" type="number" />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit ykq0828zr9]

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure that I understood well: I do not see `<Grid item xs={true}>` in your code. You use `<Grid item xs={4} sm={3} md>`. Is it auto-layout?

Comment: It is auto-layout for medium. `md` is equivalent to `md={true}`.

Comment: I tested `<Grid item xs={true}>` and it does well auto-scaling. Could you please explain the difference between `<Grid item xs={true}>` and `<Grid item xs={4} sm={3} md>`. Which approach would you recommend for a responsive web app?

Comment: Yes, `<Grid item xs>` or `<Grid item xs={true}>` does what you were asking for. I was just demonstrating some of the flexibility of what is possible. 7 text fields side-by-side aren't very usable on mobile because only 3 or 4 characters fit visibly in each one. If all 7 fields are just entering 2 or 3-digit numbers, that may be fine. With `<Grid xs={3} sm>`, for example, you could choose to use auto-layout for 600px and wider, but 4 text fields per line for the smallest screens.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used material-ui myself, but seems like the grid system is similar to bootstrap.

Based on my bootstrap understanding, the grid system is locked by the 12-grid rule. You cannot put anything that's bigger than 12. If it's more than 12, it will be added to the next line.

For your question, `xs={1}` means 1 of 12 length, so if you have 7 items, it won't fit the screen as it will only have 7 of 12 length. However, if you increase the length into `xs={2}` you'd have 14 of 12, so it will overflow to the next line.

The solution is to just don't use the grid system for this exact problem since the grid system isn't suited for your case, use custom style with something like flexbox without the grid system.

If you have 2/3/4/6 elements, you can use the grid system and you can easily adjust the size for those elements.